# Definite integration stuck on putting limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Okay can somebody demonstrate how to put this limit $x=0$ to $x=\infty$ in this expression?

$$ \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4}\log(x^2+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(x+1)+\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}x\right) \mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: This is unreadable-consider typing in mathjax-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can you format your question so that can be read?  Also, can you add a question?  You've just written a long string of equations, without indicating your confusion.

Comment: The question has been edited please answer now

Comment: Before you had infinity, and now $\pi$ which is it?

Comment: It is infinity. Sure about that

Comment: Maybe the purpose of the question is to get help with mathjax of "lim". Is that the case?

Comment: @mathreadler i think you are right.

Comment: You can write \lim_{x \to 0} or \lim_{x \to \infty} in the mathjax / latex environment with double \$ signs, like this: $$\lim_{x \to 0} or \lim_{x \to \infty}$$

Comment: Wait is it for an integral? Doh.

Comment: This is a poorly stated Question, with the problem being posed in the title and then some details in the body that are not directly tied together.  Please use the body of the Question to give a full (self-contained) problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fas as I know, when a function does not exist for the given limits you need to take the limiting case. In the above case, $\tan^{-1}x$ should not be a problem.
$\frac{1}{4}\log(x^2+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(x+1)$ = $\frac{1}{4}\log\frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2}
$ Now for $x={\infty}$ take $\lim_\limits{x\to{\infty}}\frac{1}{4}\log\frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2}$ which is $\lim_\limits{x\to{\infty}}\frac{1}{4}\log\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}{(\frac{1}{x}+1)^2}$ which is $\log1$ which is zero. For $\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{1}{4}\log\frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2}$ the expression also boils down to $\log1$ which is zero. So the answer should just be $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume the question is about how to write integrals in LaTeX & MathJax.

You can type integrals like this, using the "\int" command:

\$\$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx\$\$

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

so \$\$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx\$\$
becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

this syntax with \$\command_{stuff}^{staff}{stiff}\$ is quite common for different commands in LaTeX.

[You can (and are encouraged to) read more about syntax for LaTeX and MathJax here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).